# can the empty set be an element of a group?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

is the following group legal: $x = \{1,2,\emptyset\}$?
If so, is $P(x) = \{ \emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}, \{\emptyset\}, \{1, \emptyset\}, \{2,\emptyset\}, \{1,2,\emptyset\} \}$ ?

When I write group, I mean set (Translation problems)

Answer (score 3):

If by group you mean "set", sure. It's a legitimate set. Note that if $A$ is a set, then the empty set is an element of the **power *set*** of $A$.

And yes, you have computed the power set correctly.

Comment: but my question is if one of the elements of A is the empty set, will the power set of A contain both the empty set, and a set containing the empty set (as I've written in my question)?

Comment: yes, precisely.  consider $\mathscr{P}(\mathscr{P}(\mathscr{P}(\emptyset)))$.  In particular some elements will appear as $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$.  Anything may be an element of a set, whether it is a set containing a set containing the empty set, or your friend George and his pet dog.

Answer (score 0):

*Is the following set legal: $x = \{1,2, \emptyset \} $ ?*

Yes.

*If so, is $P(x) = \{ \emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}, \{\emptyset\}, \{1, \emptyset\}, \{2,\emptyset\}, \{1,2,\emptyset\} \} $ ?*

Yes.